# Javascript - Loop through datastructure

Tags: javascript, beginner

I know my solution works, but I would like to know if the function can be simplified so that the loop is not called twice. Is there a way to pass the properties to be run through as parameters in the function?

My given data structure looks like (in which `totalQuantities` and `typeQuantities` might contain an uncertain amount of objects):

```
data = [
  {
    "totalQuantities": [
      {
        "ammount": 23
      }
    ],
    "typeQuantities": [
      {
        "type": {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Test"
        },
        "singleQuantities": [
          {
            "ammount": 45
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My desired output is:

```
values = [
    {type: 'Total', ammount1: 23},
    {type: 'Test1', ammount1: 45}
]
```

And my solution - of which I'm wondering if there is another way to do so - is:

```
transformData(data) {
  const values = [];
  // loop through totalQuantities
  const objTotal: any = {};
  objTotal.type = 'Total';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.totalQuantities.length; i++) {
    const name = 'ammount' + (i + 1).toString();
    objTotal[name] = data.totalQuantities[i].ammount;
  }
  values.push(objTotal);
  // loop through each element of singleQuantities
  data.typeQuantities.map(element => {
    const obj: any = {};
    obj.type = element.type.name;
    for (let i = 0; i < element.singleQuantities.length; i++) {
      const name = 'ammount' + (i + 1).toString();
      obj[name] = element.singleQuantities[i].ammount;
    }
    values.push(obj);
  });
  return values;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: **ammount** instead of **amount**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using TypeScript. TypeScript is great - it can turn difficult-to-debug runtime errors into trivially fixable compile errors. But for this sort of type checking to work:

**Don't use `any`**, since it effectively disables type checking for that expression. TSLint rule: [`no-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/). Better to think about what the data structure will be, and type the expression appropriately.

**Proper spelling** is more professional and helps prevent bugs. Consider changing all the occurrences of `ammount` to `amount`.

**Use an array instead of numerically indexed properties in an object**, if at all possible - it'll make more sense as a data structure and will make iteration over it easier. For example, instead of having something like:

```
{type: 'Total', ammount1: 23, ammount2: 99, ammount3: 555},
```

would it be possible to tweak the user of the object to accept instead:

```
{type: 'Total', amounts: [23, 99, 555]}
```

? If I were you, I'd exert a significant amount of effort into making this change possible; it'd be a good structural improvement.

**Use `.map` only when constructing an array by transforming every element of another array** - if what you do inside the map is *side-effects* like `.push`, it would be more appropriate to use a generic iteration method like `.forEach`. But using `.map` and returning an object will make the code easier:

```js
const data=[{totalQuantities:[{amount:23}],typeQuantities:[{type:{id:0,name:"Test"},singleQuantities:[{amount:45}]}]}];

const transformData = (data) => {
  const objTotal = {
    type: 'total',
    amounts: data.totalQuantities.map(({ amount }) => amount)
  };
  const typeQuantitiesObjs = data.typeQuantities.map(element => ({
    type: element.type.name,
    amounts: element.singleQuantities.map(({ amount }) => amount)
  }));
  return [objTotal, ...typeQuantitiesObjs];
};

console.log(transformData(data[0]));
```

TypeScript works really well when all of your data transformation is *pure*, as done in the above snippet. When you construct arrays and objects outright instead of mutating them inside a loop, TypeScript can often infer the resulting types automatically, which means that the code doesn't have much type-related syntax, and can look just like JavaScript (and so is easy to read) - *despite still being type-safe*.

> so that the loop is not called twice

I think the two data sources are too different for this to be done in an easy-to-understand way: one uses `type: 'total'`, the other uses `type: element.type.name,`. Also, one uses `.totalQuantities` to get the quantities, and the other uses `.singleQuantities`.

While it would be *possible* to refactor to avoid the repetition of `{ type: .., amounts: ... }`, it would look somewhat convoluted; I wouldn't recommend it, it'll be harder to make sense of at a glance.

If the output objects must contain `amount1` etc instead of a single array, I'd make a helper function that can transform an array of input quantities objects into a properly formatted object with `Object.fromEntries`, then call that function for both the `total` and the `typeQuantities`:

```js
const data=[{totalQuantities:[{amount:23}],typeQuantities:[{type:{id:0,name:"Test"},singleQuantities:[{amount:45}]}]}];

const getAmounts = quantities => Object.fromEntries(
  quantities.map(
    ({ amount }, i) => ['amount' + (i + 1), amount]
  )
);
const transformData = (data) => {
  const objTotal = {
    type: 'total',
    ...getAmounts(data.totalQuantities)
  };
  const typeQuantitiesObjs = data.typeQuantities.map(element => ({
    type: element.type.name,
    ...getAmounts(element.singleQuantities)
  }));
  return [objTotal, ...typeQuantitiesObjs];
};

console.log(transformData(data[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I surely agree with you on the typing and spelling. Unluckily the output has to be an object like '{type: 'Total', amount1: 23, amount2: 99, amount3: 555}' because it is passed on to a table which requires this kind of structure. Anyway it helps a lot to see that even more experienced coders recommend to keep a certain value of readability to the code!

Comment: If the data is used for display immediately instead of being passed along to some other data processor, having separate `amount1` etc properties sounds fine to me.

Comment: Thank you! You're solution looks much  more structured than mine - that was, what I was looking for